How to create columns instead rows in Logstash with aggregate plugin
I have a log similar to this and I need to get these lines and upload in kibana:
[03/07/2024 00:00:31.306][123456][newRequest][Request][Company|signature|L|id|123456789|0987654321]
[03/07/2024 00:00:31.634][123456][Company][Signature][Result][eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInBwdCI6InNoYWtlb]

My logstash config:
input{
    file{
        path => ["L:/FileServer/*.log"]
        start_position => "beginning"
        stat_interval => "60000 s"
        discover_interval => 1
        tags => EXTRALOG
    }
}

    if "EXTRALOG" in [tags] {
        grok {
            match => ["message", "\[%{DATESTAMP:timestamp}\]\[%{WORD:taskid}\]\[%{WORD:req_process}\]\[%{WORD:req_type}\]\[%{GREEDYDATA:req_body}\]"]
        }
        grok {
            match => ["message", "\[%{DATESTAMP:timestamp}\]\[%{WORD:taskid}\]\[%{WORD:res_company}\]\[%{WORD:res_process}\]\[%{WORD:res_type}\]\[%{GREEDYDATA:res_body}\]"]
        }
        
        if [req_process] == "newRequest" and [req_type] == "Request"{
            aggregate {
                task_id => "%{taskid}"
                code => "map['req_body'] = event.get('req_body')"
                map_action => "create"
                add_field => {
                    "req_body" => "%{req_body}"
                    "res_body" => ""
                }
            }
        } else if [res_process] == "Signature" and [res_type] == "Result"{
            aggregate {
                task_id => "%{taskid}"
                code => "map['res_body'] = event.get('res_body')"
                map_action => "update"
                add_field => {
                    "res_body" => "%{res_body}"
                }
            }
        }else{
            drop { }
        }
    }
    if "EXTRALOG" in [tags] {
        elasticsearch {
            ssl_certificate_verification => false
            user => elastic
            password => abc12345
            hosts => [ "https://localhost:9200" ]
            index => "service_log"
        }
    }

I'm trying to create three columns (taskid,request,response) and display them in kibana

however I get a row with taskid and request and other with taskid and response.

What is the issue or I'm using a wrong plugin?
